# JFreeChart - move value of line chart to bottom

Tags: java, charts, line, jfreechart

Do you know if it is possible to move the value on a line chart to the bottom of the axis ( like the 0,64 on the left) ?

[image]

Or , if not possible, to display the value juste below the line ?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely is to search some property which involed with values of: Bottom/Middle/Center. May try to create a font with bottom position

Comment: You can't get this result directly using the API, but you could subclass the renderer and override the calculateLabelAnchorPoint() method (inherited from the AbstractRenderer class) to return any anchor point that you want (in your case, one where the y value is near the bottom of the data area).